# Wordpress Shortcode to display featured images only

Tags: images, shortcode

I'm looking for a simple shortcode to pull in featured images without the blogpost title.  Currently I am using:

```
[display-posts category="OSH" image_size="standard"]
```

which works, but with the titles.  What do I change?

Comment: do you have access to the theme functions.php file?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you're using [Display Posts Shortcode](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/) does include a parameter to disable post titles: `include_title="false"`

So your shortcode would look like this:

```
[display-posts category="OSH" include_title="false" image_size="standard"]
```

Hope that helps.